# HtmlUnit WebClient Session Duration

Tags: java, session, htmlunit

I am making command line tool to visit web sites multiple times. I am using multiple threads to access page at a time and each thread repeat visiting web site using loops. Tool is working fine and it visit web sites as required but the only problem is faced that it open website and close it after few moments. So session duration of each visit is limited to 3 to 4 seconds. I need to increase this session duration to minimum 60 seconds. Below is my code.

```
package directUrl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

public class ThreadDirectUrl extends Thread {

    private String url;
    private String paramUserAgent;
    private String paramReferer;
    private int loopSize;

    public ThreadDirectUrl(String url, String paramUserAgent, String paramReferer, int loopSize) {
        this.url = url;
        this.paramUserAgent = paramUserAgent;
        this.paramReferer = paramReferer;
        this.loopSize = loopSize;
    }

    public void run() {
        String userAgent = new String();

        // Get User Agent
        if (paramUserAgent.equals("1")) {
            userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0";
        } else if (paramUserAgent.equals("2")) {
            userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1";
        } else if (paramUserAgent.equals("3")) {
            userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7";
        } else if (paramUserAgent.equals("4")) {
            userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1";
        }

        BrowserVersion bv = new BrowserVersion("Netscape", "Version", userAgent, 0);

        try {
            URL openUrl = new URL(url);
            for (int i = 1; i <= loopSize; i++) {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient(bv);
                webClient.addRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "compress, gzip");
                webClient.addRequestHeader("Referer", paramReferer);
                webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(true);
                webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
                webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
                webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
                webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true);
                webClient.getOptions().setMaxInMemory(3);
                webClient.getPage(openUrl);

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "----" + i + "----\nSuccess!\nUser Agent: "
                        + bv.getUserAgent() + "\n\n");
                Thread.sleep(60000);
                webClient.getCurrentWindow().getJobManager().removeAllJobs();
                webClient.close();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "COMPLETED");

        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error - Use URL with \"http://\" or \"https://\"!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Interrupted");
        } finally {

            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

Main class is as below

```
package directUrl;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DirectUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Production Variables
        String url = args[0]; // URL
        String paramUserAgent = args[1]; // User Agent Choice
        String paramReferer = args[2]; // Referrer URL
        int loopSize = Integer.parseInt(args[3]); // Loop Size
        int threadSize = Integer.parseInt(args[4]); // Counts of threads

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
        logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);

        // Create Multiple Threads
        ThreadDirectUrl aThread;
        for (int i = 1; i <= threadSize; i++) {
            aThread = new ThreadDirectUrl(url, paramUserAgent, paramReferer, loopSize);
            aThread.setName("thread" + i);
            aThread.start();
        }

    }

}
```

In the class ThreadDirectUrl, I have used;

```
Thread.sleep(60000);
```

after getPage() method but it is not working. Please suggest.

Comment: What error do you get after `sleep?`, you can see the cookies in headers by `LogManager.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.ALL);` please post sample URL

Comment: @AhmedAshour No error.

Comment: So, what do you expect? You get a page (with implicit session), what should be done next? what `it is not working`.

Comment: I just need to make sure that session duration is greater then 00:01:00 but currently it shows duration of only 00:00:01 or 00:00:02. OR It can be described that I want to increase the visit duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If if want the server to see the session to live longer, then do something with client.

E.g. load the same page again:

```
webClient.getPage(openUrl);

Thread.sleep(60000);

// then get the same page again
webClient.getPage(openUrl);
```

Comment: I did the same before you posted the answer and it worked after doing some research that how server see session durations. But I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks, also try to use latest 2.25, which was just released.